# Getting connection refused in k8s pods when trying to connect to other pods in the same namespace

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am setting up a prometheus-stack of version  --version 14.6.2  in K8s EKS 1.22 created by EKSCTL, My issue is that while the Prometheus stack came up and running i am getting  connection refused when trying to test the connection from grafana to prometheus

```
t=2022-07-11T17:47:49+0000 lvl=eror msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin method=GET path=/api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/query status=502 remote_addr=10.9.144.219 time_ms=1026 size=0 referer=https://monitoring.dev.cognizer.ai/datasources/edit/1/
t=2022-07-11T17:48:32+0000 lvl=eror msg="Data proxy error" logger=data-proxy-log userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin path=/api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/query remote_addr=10.9.144.219 referer=https://monitoring.dev.cognizer.ai/datasources/edit/1/ error="http: proxy error: dial tcp 172.20.253.126:9090: connect: connection refused"
```

I am facing the same connection refused issue in efk stack as well in EKS k8s 1.22.

```
[2022/07/11 06:52:51] [error] [upstream] connection #57 to elasticsearch-master:9200 timed out after 10 seconds
[2022/07/11 06:52:51] [error] [upstream] connection #76 to elasticsearch-master:9200 timed out after 10 seconds
[2022/07/11 06:52:53] [error] [upstream] connection #74 to elasticsearch-master:9200 timed out after 10 seconds
[2022/07/11 06:52:53] [error] [upstream] connection #61 to elasticsearch-master:9200 timed out after 10 seconds
[2022/07/11 06:52:53] [error] [upstream] connection #81 to elasticsearch-master:9200 timed out after 10 seconds
```

I have verified all the default security groups are created by eksctl and allowing all ports inside the worked nodes

Any pointers on where i need to check

Comment: Did you check and ensure that all the pods of your cluster were running fine? This seems like either the pods are not running, or listening on the wrong ports.

Comment: All pods are in running state and they were running on same ports as these were sourced from the helm chart of promethues stack `prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack` and the efk is started by these charts `  - name: elasticsearch
    version: "7.15.0"
    repository: "https://helm.elastic.co"
  - name: fluent-bit
    version: "0.19.1"
    repository: "https://fluent.github.io/helm-charts"
  - name: kibana
    version: "7.16.1"`